# Retrofit2 scalar converter not converting before gson converter android

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I have the following retrofit2 in Android with the scalar converter factory first and gson converter after but when I call a String Call and the response comes as a string it gives me the exeption "Not a JSON object: "success".

Am I missing anything?

Retrofit creation:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(IPService.END)
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
                .build();
```

Call creation:

```
@POST("/friends/sendRequest")
Call<String> sendFriendRequest(...);
```

Call Execution:

```
Response<String> a =  myApi.sendFriendRequest(...).execute();
```

Reponse body is "Success".

Comment: there need to be some `jsonkey` like the response should be `{"responsemessage":"Success"}`. That's why it's throwing exception

Comment: can you post the response as it is in the log or on postman?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this isn't possible to use Gson and Scalar. Retrofit can't recognize if it's plain string response or json string response.

My way is to use Scalar converter only, return everywhere String, and then manually convert it in stream using Gson.

Below example in Kotlin with RxJava

```
@GET("{path}")
    fun getVersion(@Path("path") hash: String): Single<String>

api.getVersion()
                .map { val gson =  GsonBuilder()
                        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                        .create()
                        gson.fromJson(it, VersionResponse::class.java)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that because Scalar can't work with wraped by Call